# PhpStorm not loading Angular project files

Tags: angular, phpstorm, angular-cli

Every time I open my projects, app folder contents does not load. I closed project, deleted `.idea` folder, invalidated caches, but still having same bug.

Please, has anybody ever met this before ?

[image: check screenshot here]

Comment: Contact JetBrains Support for this kind of issues -- they will need some info about the project / your IDE logs in order to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Please do as advised above. There could be lots of possible environment-specific reasons for that.

Answer (score 0):

You must have either the [typescript-folding](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15454-typescript-folding) or the [Angular Component Folding](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10090-angular-component-folding) plugins (or both) enabled; they are known for causing such issues